# Null pointer exception when trying to modify Fragment GUI Items through Interfaces

Tags: android

I have an activity containing a `ViewPager` in which are located 3 fragments. 
When activity get location info (in the `onConnected` method), I would like it to pass the information to a fragment which should change the content of one its `TextView`.

I implemented the information passing using an Interface created in the `MainActivity` and than the fragment implement the method needed to get the location info and modify the `TextView`.

Here comes the problem: the implemented method, when called seems to not find the `TextView`, and it rises a `NullpointerException`.

```
public class FragmentTab4 extends Fragment implements MainActivity.LocationHandler {

    View view;
    TextView textView;
    public TextView location;
    public Context context;
    ListView listViewMessages22;
    MessageLayoutAdapter adapter;
    Button writeMessageButton;
    private Bundle args = new Bundle();
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    //public static final String TAG = FragmentTab4.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Get the view from fragmenttab2.xml
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab4, container, false);
        context = getActivity();
        writeMessageButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonWriteMessage);
        writeMessageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(view.getContext().getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //open popup to write message
                WriteMessageDialog writeMessageDialog = new WriteMessageDialog();
                writeMessageDialog.setArguments(args);
                writeMessageDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "iuuu" );
            }
        });
        location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_location);
        //Location loc = LocationService.getInstance(getActivity()).getLocation();
        location.setText("Getting location...");

        if(((MainActivity)context).mLastLocation!=null){

            Location ll = ((MainActivity)context).mLastLocation;
            location.setText("Coordinates: "+ll.getLatitude()+" "+ll.getLongitude());
        }else{

            location.setText("Nothing...");
        }
        //location.setText("Coordinats: "+loc.getLatitude()+" "+loc.getLongitude());
        //textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        listViewMessages22 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewMessages20);
        List<Message> bacheca1 = new ArrayList<Message>();

        //adapter = new MessageLayoutAdapter(container.getContext(), R.layout.message, bacheca1);
        Log.d(TAG,"Adapter ok.............");
        //listViewMessages22.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d(TAG," ok .............");

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleNewLocation(Location loc) {

        //location.setText("Coordinates: "+loc.getLatitude()+" "+loc.getLongitude());
        Log.d(TAG,"Siamo giunti in Fragment4 - handleNewLocation "+loc.getLatitude()+" "+loc.getLongitude());
        location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_location);
    }
```

Here is the MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener{

    ActionBar actionBar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    Context context1;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    public Location mLastLocation;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    LocationHandler mLocationHandler;
    LocationService locator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context1 = getApplicationContext();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY).setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setNumUpdates(20)
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

        locator = LocationService.getInstance(this);

        if(!checkPlayServices()){

            finish();
        }
        //create GoogleApiClient
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        //locator.setGoogleClient(mGoogleApiClient);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {

            mLocationHandler = (LocationHandler) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
        } catch (ClassCastException e){

            Log.d(TAG, "=== Problem connecting the fragment to the activity ===");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        Log.d(TAG, "On connected........||||||||||||");
        getLocation();
        //viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        if(mLastLocation!=null){

            mLocationHandler.handleNewLocation(mLastLocation);
            //locator.setLocation(mLastLocation);
        }else{

            mLocationHandler.alertMissingLocation();
        }

        //FragmentTab4 fragment = (FragmentTab4) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
        //fragment.alertMissingLocation();
    }
```

This is the log output:

```
04-24 17:30:10.121  30668-30668/? D/MainActivity﹕ On Location changed....
04-24 17:30:10.131  30668-30668/? D/MainActivity﹕ requested new loc
04-24 17:30:10.131  30668-30668/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.vlaveglia.appwithtab, PID: 30668
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at        com.example.vlaveglia.appwithtab.bacheca.FragmentTab4.handleNewLocation(FragmentTab4.java:102)
        at com.example.vlaveglia.appwithtab.MainActivity.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:169)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpe$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The ViewPager is

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;
// Tab Titles
private String tabtitles[] = new String[] { "Bacheca", "Annunci", "Mappa" , "Prova4"};
Context context;
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        // Open FragmentTab1.java
        case 3:
            FragmentTab1 fragmenttab1 = new FragmentTab1();
            return fragmenttab1;
        // Open FragmentTab2.java
        case 1:
            FragmentTab2 fragmenttab2 = new FragmentTab2();
            return fragmenttab2;
        // Open FragmentTab3.java
        case 2:
            FragmentTab3 fragmenttab3 = new FragmentTab3();
            return fragmenttab3;
        case 0:
            FragmentTab4 fragmenttab4 = new FragmentTab4();
            return fragmenttab4;
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabtitles[position];
}
```

}

Comment: `NullPointerException` you say? The Logcat to us you should post, since my crystal ball forgot I have.

Comment: Ok so tell me these: 1. what is line 102 in FragmentTab4 ? 2. How do you instantiate FragmentTab4 in viewPagerAdapter ? Because I don't see it in MainActivity. Please know that my solution may not work with ViewPager. ViewPager has many fragments and each fragment may be destroyed and rebuilt if you go from one fragment to another. You probably need to use EventBus / Otto for this purpose.

Comment: I added the ViewPager code in my question. The `grabURL()` at line 102 make an http requests and downloads the file

Comment: Ok I see. In ViewPager not all fragments are created in the same time. The first fragment or FragmentTab1 is the first one created. If you move to second fragment then FragmentTab2 is created. If you move to third fragment, FragmentTab3 is created AND FragmentTab1 is destroyed. When your onLocationChanged in your MainActivity gets a new location, it calls handleNewLocation if FragmentTab4 which is not created. I believe line 102 in your error log FragmentTab4.handleNewLocation(FragmentTab4.java:102) is location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_location);.

Answer (score 0):

This is a concurrency problem. This method `public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)` is a callback of `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`. This does not depend on the availability of your Fragment. So `handleNewLocation` might be called too early before the fragment builds its view.

One way to reduce the risk of fragment not available on receiving location callback is to initiate location request *after* your fragment has been created. Create a listener like this

```
public interface MyFragmentListener {
   public void onViewCreated();
}
```

which you call in your Fragment

```
MyFragmentListener myFragmentListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    myFragmentListener = (MyFragmentListener)activity;
}    

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   myFragmentListener.onViewCreated();
}
```

Then you implement this listener in your Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements    
..., MyFragmentListener {

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(){
        //request location, I believe it's by invoking this method
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

As long as you don't plan to replace or remove the fragment then this method is ok. If you do then there will be possibility that the fragment is gone when the callback arrives, raising a null pointer exception. So I have personally abandoned this listener concept because as you see listeners are too tightly coupled with Activity or Fragment and their lifecycle. Since you are new to Android, I suggest you spend a bit of time reading Publisher-Subscriber pattern and its implementations like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

And finally don't reinitialize View (e.g don't do `location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_location);` many times). Just do once in onCreateView and use the reference directly (e.g `location.setText("aaa")`)

Comment: I dont know... I launched the application without position activated and it worked... than I turned on position, and when the application got position info the onconnected method was called and the application crashed...

Comment: Anyway there is a way to make handleNewLocation wait until Fragment is totally built? I would like to try this option too... Thank you very much!

Comment: There are so many parts missing from your code and I had to deduct with incomplete information. But if you look at your own logcat, you see 'onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:169)' which I presume the LocationListener callback. So basically a location callback and your fragment are racing to be the first. I'll edit my answer a bit to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! ...i did as you wrote, but it keeps rising the same error... in particulare the exception rises in method 'handleNewLocation' at line location.setText("hello"). Il seems that it doesn't find the object...

Comment: I tried also on the other way. I added a button to the fragment.. and in the onButtonOnClickListener I added an interface method implemented in the MainActivity. In the implementatio it just modifies the TextView content... It also rises Exception in the row that tries to modify text.

Comment: I don't know how you implemented my solution. Unless I see your code I cannot say.

Comment: In the MainActivity I solved the problem... the gui item was declared before the setContentView(). But for the Fragment the problem persists... now I attach the code...